# Android : Not getting any data in recycleview through zomato Api via retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

**Adapter class :**

```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public List<Category> mDataset;
    public Context mContext ;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;public TextView mTextView1;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mTextView1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<Category> myDataset) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;

    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       // Word1 currentAndroidFlavor = getItem(position);
            // - get element from your dataset at this position
      holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getCategories().getName());
       Log.v("check_value",mDataset.get(0).getCategories().getName()+"_value")
/*holder.mTextView1.*/;
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

**Service class :**

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("categories")
    Call<Categories> getRestaurant(@Header("Content-Type")
      String contentType, @Header("user-key")  String userKey);

}
```

**Main Activity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView ;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager ;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter ;
    private DownloadFilesTask mDownloadFilesTask ;
    private List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mDownloadFilesTask!=null && !mDownloadFilesTask.isCancelled())
        {
            mDownloadFilesTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     /*   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvCategories);
        mLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mDownloadFilesTask = new DownloadFilesTask();
        mDownloadFilesTask.execute();
*/

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCategories);
    //categoryList.add(new Category());
        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mDownloadFilesTask = new DownloadFilesTask();
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mDownloadFilesTask.execute();
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(categoryList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
       /* mAdapter = new MyAdapter(categoryList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
*/

//        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)


    }

    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/").
                            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
            Call<Categories> peopleCall = service.getRestaurant("application/json","3a20a689dce585e6cb54bd2e88c41b43");
            peopleCall.enqueue(new Callback<Categories>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResponse(Response<Categories> response, Retrofit retrofit) {


                                       Log.d("onResponse", "" + response.code() +
                                               "  response body " + response.body().getCategories().get(0).getCategories().getName() +
                                               " responseError " + response.errorBody() + " responseMessage " +
                                               response.message());
                                       categoryList =  response.body().getCategories();


                                   }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
                }




            });





            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
       //     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

**categories class (generated through pojo ):**

```
public class Categories {

    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<Category> categories = null;

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

**category class (generated through pojo):**

```
public class Category {

    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private Categories_ categories;

    public Categories_ getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Categories_ categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

**categories_ class (generated through pojo) :**

```
public class Categories_ {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

  }
```

Comment: it is skipping adapter everytime.............getting response code 200

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to create `AsyncTask` to make your retrofit request....`peopleCall.enqueue` will kick off asynchronous request.  Then to ensure your RecyclerView is updated when you get `categoryList` response you'll need to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.